# codeigniter code is not able to print image on web project

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, base-path

in my project I want to add image to show the link in which the my code is return image if I use

```
 <a href="<?= site_url('login')?>">
     <img src="<?= base_url();?>images/login.png" 
          width="32" 
          height="32" 
          border="0" />
 </a>
```

echo in php but when I use this it is not able to return image insead what is the method of base path.

```
 <a href="<?php echo site_url('login')?>">
     <img src="<?php  echo base_url();?>images/login.png" 
          width="32" 
          height="32" 
          border="0" />
 </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your image path is correct try this

```
 <a href="<?= site_url('login')?>">
     <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/login.png');?>" 
          width="32" 
          height="32" 
          border="0" />
 </a>
```

And see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

you could try this if your image path is right

```
<img src="../images/login.png"/>
```